# Spinners in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to create multiple spinner onItemSelected function but it giving me error in parent and view.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> **parent**, **View** view,
    int pos, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        TextView  tvReadValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReadValue);
        switch (parent.getId())
        {
            case R.id.spinDimension:

                tvReadValue.setText("spinDimension" + pos);

                break;

            case R.id.speedDimension:

                tvReadValue.setText("speedDimension" + pos);
                break;
        }
```

** is my error

Update. My problrm is I have 3 spinners and all have onselected implemented on them.  When I am selecting a value in first spinner. Its running on selected method of other spinners also...

Comment: error log please

Comment: you can't get id like this. instead get id from view only.

Comment: their is no error log as i am not able to run app

Comment: i have declared View view object already

Comment: @zzz You manually write this method or implemented via extend listener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 Log.d("form","onitemselected");
 switch (parent.getId()) {
 case R.id.spinDimension:
 tvReadValue.setText("spinDimension" + position);
 Log.d("form","regionid:" + r.id);
 break;
 case R.id.speedDimension:
 tvReadValue.setText("speedDimension" + position);
 Log.d("form","state id:");
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);    
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And also you can set it directly where you want it. To call on your spinner after your adapter has been set.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Spinner item 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Spinner item 2!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Spinner item 3!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       // sometimes you need nothing here
    }
});
```

Comment: The spinner I want is ... I have multiple spinners and are dependent on each other. The method of urs is giving value of each item in spinner. My problem is I have  multiple spinners which if I click on one it runs the onselect methods of other spinners too.

Comment: I didn't get much with the code you mentioned. Please add full code if possible

Comment: Sir I resolved that problem. Tge problem mentiined in update is now I m facing.

Comment: You get some help from this [http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/android-how-to-multiple-spinners-drop-down-list-view-to-app/](http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/android-how-to-multiple-spinners-drop-down-list-view-to-app/)